# Multiple Retention stages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, information-policy

I have created a list based retention Schedule with 6 different triggers, although I require them to run independently. I didn't use a workflow for this because the dates aren't used for every item and I want this automated as much as possible. Does the retention schedule work in order of appearance, or will all six of these events trigger independently? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stages in a retention policy will run serially displayed in the list.

The above stage is completed, then skip to the next stage.

Comment: does that mean if the Bring forward date is before the requirement renewal date, the bring forward step wont activate until the renewal date has been reached and it activates?